# Obtain milliseconds from date javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date format like this 2011-07-29T08:18:39

I want to convert this date intro milliseconds
I try

```
var myDate = '2011-07-29T08:18:39';    
new Date(myDate.replace("T"," ")).getTime()
```

but display me NaN.
Please help
Thanks

Comment: Be aware that your accepted solution below doesn't work on any released version of IE.

Comment: He's now updated it so it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

T.J. was correct; my original solution failed in IE9 and Safari.  This will do it, and works in all major browsers.

```
var myDate = '2011-07-29T08:18:39';    

function parseDate(dateString){
    var time = Date.parse(dateString);
    if(!time){
        time = Date.parse(dateString.replace("T"," "));
        if(!time){
            bound = dateString.indexOf('T');
            var dateData = dateString.slice(0, bound).split('-');
            var timeData = dateString.slice(bound+1, -1).split(':');

            time = Date.UTC(dateData[0],dateData[1]-1,dateData[2],timeData[0],timeData[1],timeData[2]);
        }
    }
    return time;
}

var milliseconds = parseDate(myDate);
```

Comment: In your first example, why are you replacing a `T` that isn't there? Is it a typo?

Comment: You can't rely on `Date.parse` yet, either, for the same reason you can't rely on `new Date(string)`.

Comment: Date.parse is supported by all major browsers.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Comment: Yes, `Date.parse` is defined by the 3rd edition spec, but *what it accepts* is not the ISO-8601-style date. **All** you can count on is that it accepts what `Date#toString` and `Date#toUTCString` spit out. In both cases, the spec says "...contents of the string are implementation-dependent..." (Sections 15.9.5.2 and 15.9.5.42). Browsers *may* go beyond that, but not all do. IE doesn't support it, not even IE9: http://jsbin.com/otupum/2

Comment: AWinter: You don't know who downvoted the answer. You know that I commented, and you know that someone downvoted. That's all you know. It's frequently the case that the person commenting did not downvote, and that the person downvoting did not comment. (Not *this* time, I did downvote because this solution doesn't work, and that's what downvoting is for.)

Comment: T.J you're right in that the original solution did not work. I've updated the solution to a working version.

Comment: Another minor typo - you are defining myDate in your example globally, and then using it within the scope of your method. You should be parsing dateString instead.

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't getting the milliseconds (you're doing that right), it's getting the date.

A lot of browsers still don't support that string format, including all released versions of IE, even IE9. That's because that ISO-8601-style format was only added to the specification in the 5th edition, about a year and a half ago; prior to that, the previous spec just said that they had to accept whatever `Date#toString` and `Date#toUTCString` spat out, and *those* were defined as "implementation-dependent" strings. E.g., you can't rely on their format. At all.

Until the changes in the 5th edition spec are implemented more widely (and then several years go by until older browsers aren't still used by a significant fraction of the userbase), you'll have to parse the format yourself, or use something like [DateJS](http://datejs.com) to do it for you.

DateJS is really very cool, but if you don't want to use it, parsing that format is dead easy provided your source is always giving you exactly that format ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/amuqip)):

```
var myDate, parts, date, time, dt, ms;

myDate = '2011-07-29T08:18:39';
parts = myDate.split(/[T ]/); // Split on `T` or a space to get date and time
date = parts[0];
time = parts[1];

dt = new Date();

parts = date.split(/[-\/]/);  // Split date on - or /
dt.setFullYear(parseInt(parts[0], 10));
dt.setMonth(parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1); // Months start at 0 in JS
dt.setDate(parseInt(parts[2], 10));

parts = time.split(/:/);    // Split time on :
dt.setHours(parseInt(parts[0], 10));
dt.setMinutes(parseInt(parts[1], 10));
dt.setSeconds(parseInt(parts[2], 10));

ms = dt.getTime(); // or ms = +dt; if you want to be l33t about it
```