# JavaScript date() Object returns NaN with getYear (and other)

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I am currently having some issues converting a string dateTime object in JavaScript

I am assuming it is because my string cannot me used properly in a `new Date()` but I'm not sure that is the problem.

My Input: "2011-09-29 14:58:12"

My code:

```
var date = "2011-09-29 14:58:12";
var added = new Date(date);
var year = added.getYear();
```

However, my `year` var contains NaN. Same with getDay() or getMonth(). What is the problem?

ps: I'm getting the date in it's format from a SQLite database. And I'm using Titanium Mobile, so javascript and SQLite are the only things involved

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're relying on the [`Date` constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-constructor) parsing an unsupported format. Until recently, there was *no* standard string format supported by the `Date` constructor. As of ECMAScript5, there is one (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`, note the `T` rather than space), but it's only been specified for just under two years and naturally doesn't work in older browsers.

For the time being, your best bet is to parse it yourself (you can find code in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870431/obtain-milliseconds-from-date-javascript)), or use something like [DateJS](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs), [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/), etc. to parse it for you.

Comment: how to do this in JavaScript or SQLite?

Comment: @Topener: See [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870431/obtain-milliseconds-from-date-javascript) for the JavaScript code to do it. But again, I encourage you to look at a library like DateJS.

Answer (score -4):

The `Date` constructor will not parse a string for you.  You'll need to use `Date.parse` to do that.  Interestingly enough, `Date.parse` doesn't actually return a `Date`.  Instead it returns a unix timestamp.  You can then pass the unix timestamp into the `Date` constructor to get what you're looking for.

```
var d = new Date(Date.parse("2011-09-29 14:58:12"));
```

Comment: *"The Date constructor will not parse a string for you."* Yes, it will; [details](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.2). If you pass the `Date` constructor a string, it will parse it according to the same rules as `Date.parse`. Neither of them is documented as parsing that format.