# Javascript function and unexpected 'NAN'

Tags: javascript, date, time

I try to write a function to convert date and time from string to date. Here's my code:

```
var date_one = '2015-08-12 14:15:00'; 
var date_two = '2015-08-13 15:00:00';
console.log(date_one); //2015-08-12 14:15:00
console.log(date_two); //2015-08-13 15:00:00


var timeStamp_date_one = new Date(date_one).getTime() ; //NAN?
console.log(typeof timeStamp_date_one);//number 
var timeStamp_date_two = new Date(date_two).getTime() ;//NAN?
console.log(typeof timeStamp_date_two);//number 

//since you are having both datetime in numer time 
//you can compare then to any logical oparation ( >, < ,= ,!= ,== ,!== ,>= AND <=) 


//to be able to work with this date and time agin you need to convert it to an object 
var newTime = new Date(timeStamp_date_one) ;
console.log(typeof newTime) ;//object 

// you can the use this following function to convert your date and time to any format you want 
console.log(DateAndTimeFormat(newTime  , 'time')) ;//  NaN:NaN ???
console.log(DateAndTimeFormat(newTime  , 'date_time')) ;//  NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN ???
function DateAndTimeFormat(dateAndTime, type) {
                switch (type) {
                    case 'time':
                        return dateAndTime.getHours() + ':' + (dateAndTime.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + 
                            dateAndTime.getMinutes()
                    case 'date':
                        return dateAndTime.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + dateAndTime.getDate() + '/' +
                            dateAndTime.getFullYear()
                    case 'date_time':
                        return dateAndTime.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + dateAndTime.getDate() + '/' +
                            dateAndTime.getFullYear() + ' ' + dateAndTime.getHours() + ':' +
                            (dateAndTime.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + dateAndTime.getMinutes()

                }
            }
```

Why in this case I talways take a "Not-a-Number" value ? I expect that Object could be transfered to Data object like in this code. Somebody can told my why and how can I repair that code? Thank's a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript date() Object returns NaN with getYear (and other)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610886/javascript-date-object-returns-nan-with-getyear-and-other)

Comment: What does `console.log(timeStamp_date_one)` output?

Comment: you could also try `new Date("2015/08/12 12:09:36");`

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date, when working with years like you are doing, the format is not "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" but "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" (Notice the 'T' instead of the space)

```
var date_one = '2015-08-12T14:15:00'; 
var date_two = '2015-08-13T15:00:00';
```

With these values, your code works.

This is relative to the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns the wrong date and time for me in Chrome because of my timezone offset.

Comment: With 'T' is workin very well. Output: 14:15 8/12/2015 14:15

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to parse and split into chunks the string representing the date first and then use `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);` constructor to be 100% sure there are no any local date format issues.